# Unauthorized clone of our site, how to have it removed?

Tags: abuse

Someone has set up a proxy copy of a site we manage. The site looks completely identical except the URL is of course different (ours as a subdomain), also, most/all link hovertext says `javascript:void(0)`. The company phone number has been swapped out to another number that forwards to the original number. (are they recording these calls?)

The proxy is live, so I control the content of the clone. (funny, huh)

I'd like to contact the ISP for this server equipment and have them address this on copyright or other grounds. How can I determine the ISP, or other information that may help.

Also, is there a known correct way that a webmaster or sever admin should handle situations like this? (I'm sure there's some non-technical legal courses that should be followed.)

Comment: You told a subdomain, does that mean they got a similar domain ? Can you explain that part please

Comment: If they really are proxying, block the proxy IPs. Other than that, this is entirely a legal issue.

Comment: @yagmoth555, That is correct. It is similar looking, as they put our name in their subdomain.

Comment: @yoonix, We've blocked the IP. I was just asking in case there was a proper channel through the ISP instead of 'only' the legal system.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your replies to the question until a few months later. :-)